# Is there a libXrandr API documentation?

Tags: linux, x11, c++, xrandr

I want to use libXrandr in C++. Is there a suitable documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [project page](http://www.x.org/wiki/libraries/libxrandr) and [project repository](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXrandr/).

Reasonable Linux distributions come with man pages, which might be split-off into a -devel package (for example on Slackware you need `libXrandr`, on openSUSE it would be  `libXrandr-devel`) - `Xrandr(3)` is a good starting point.

Comment: The project repository helped me immensely! I can't find type defintions though for like sruct of like XRROutputInfo etc

Comment: You probably didn't look at [include/X11/extensions/Xrandr.h:283](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXrandr/tree/include/X11/extensions/Xrandr.h#n283). [`ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or similar utility might help next time.

Comment: There is no documentation of the library API on the project page. They just describe the protocol and talk about xrandr like if it was just the command line tool, no mention about using it as a library.

Comment: `xrandr` *is* just a command line tool - pretty much a thin wrapper around libXrandr. But if you for whatever reason need to use libXrandr, looking at `xrandr` source would be a reasonable place to start (since there is no documentation per se).